# Не работает Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Всех приветствую.
Хочу пути вынести отдельно в файл **routes** из **AppRouter**, но не получается.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, не могу разобраться.
Ошибка в браузере (последние две)
[image]

Исходные файлы

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import AppRouter from "./components/UI/AppRouter";
import Navbar from "./components/UI/Navbar/Navbar";
import './styles/app.css';


function App() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Navbar/>
                <AppRouter/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
}
          
export default App;
```

AppRouter

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import {routes} from "../../router/routes"

const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
           {routes.map(route => 
                <Route 
                    element={route.element}
                    path={route.path}
                    exact={route.exact}
                />
           )}
         <Route
             path="*"
             element={<Navigate to ='/posts'/>}>
         </Route>
   </Routes>  
    );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

routes

```js
import About from "../pages/About"
import Posts from "../pages/Posts"
import PostIdPage  from "../pages/PostIdPage"

export const routes = [
    {path: '/about', element: About, exact: true},
    {path: '/posts', element: Posts, exact: true},
    {path: '/posts/:id', element: PostIdPage, exact: true},

]
```

Заранее всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Привет! Там ошибка в том что необходимо добавить уникальный ключ key, в библиотеке React Routes это главная особенность,  ключ key с индексами элементов добавляеться в компонент.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код должен быть представлен текстом, а не картинками, как и текст ошибки. Картинки уместны только в случае, если они дополняют вопрос

Comment: Вставил текстом. А куда именно нужно ключ  добавить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React требует ключ key с индексами элементов в компоненте.

Пример с кодом:

```
    import ToggleComponent from './components/ToggleComponent'

    function App() {
        const toggleBtn = [
            {name: 'OFF - 1', stateName: 'ON - 1', cont: '123456789'},
            {name: 'OFF - 2', stateName: 'ON - 2', cont: '123456789'},
            {name: 'OFF - 3', stateName: 'ON - 3', cont: '123456789'},
            {name: 'OFF - 4', stateName: 'ON - 4', cont: '123456789'},
        ];

        return <div className='App'>

            {toggleBtn.map((text, index) => {
                return <ToggleComponent 
                                btnName={text.name}
                                btnStateName={text.stateName}
                                content={text.cont} 
                                key={index} />
            })}

        </div>
    }

    export default App
```

Comment: Текст ответа, надо было тоже скрином приложить, чего мелчиться то ) Зачем код текстом прикладывать, его ведь можно скопировать и использовать...

Comment: Картинку добавил со стрелкой, чтоб было лучше увидеть этот ключ ну и пример кода, для приличия))

Comment: Не хотите минусов за ответ, удалите картинку и добавьте код текстом. Выделить key можно и комментарием. Хотя на такой вопрос картинками, лучше вообще не отвечать.

Comment: Убрал картинку, вроде бы лучше

Comment: Лучше код с картинки вставить текстом - вот это лучше

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас поменяю код на тот что был на картинке

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Дмитрию за помощь с индексом.
В итоге  в AppRouter  исправил

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import {routes} from "../../router"

const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
            <Routes>
                {routes.map(route => 
                    <Route 
                        element={route.element}
                        path={route.path}
                        exact={route.exact}
                        key={route.path}
                    />
                )}
                <Route
                    path="*"
                    element={<Navigate to ='/posts'/>}>
                </Route>
            </Routes>  

        
    );
};
```

И в  index.js  поправил  element

```js
import About from "../pages/About"
import Posts from "../pages/Posts"
import PostIdPage  from "../pages/PostIdPage"

export const routes = [
    {path: '/about', element: <About/>, exact: true},
    {path: '/posts', element: <Posts/>, exact: true},
    {path: '/posts/:id', element: <PostIdPage/>, exact: true},

]
```

И все заработало.

Comment: Отлично! Рад, что у вас все получилось!)))